# Apply the same properties to all my Polygons

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to apply the same properies to all my Polygons:

```
Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
polygon.StrokeThickness = 2;
polygon.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
polygon.Fill = (Brush)FindResource("HatchBrush");
polygon.ToolTip = (Image)FindResource("GapImg");
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Style` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.style.aspx).

Define your style in a resource dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="PolygonStyle" TargetType="Polygon">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource HatchBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource GapImg}" />
</Style>
```

And then use [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource%28v=vs.90%29) for each `Polygon`:

```
Polygon polygon = new Polygon() 
{ 
    Style = FindResource("PolygonStyle") as Style,
};
```

If you need to apply the style **to all** your polygons just remove the `x:Key` and you will not even need to find the resource *run-time*.

Comment: You just just omit the x:key and have it apply to all polygons without having to find the resource and set it's style.

Answer (score 1):

Place the style that you've given in XAML in the App.xaml file.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication10.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <!-- Demo resources -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HatchBrush" Color="Red"/>
        <Image x:Key="GapImg" Source=".."/>

        <Style x:Key="PolygonStyle" TargetType="Polygon">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource HatchBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource GapImg}"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

If the resources HatchBrush and GapImg are created at runtime then you'll need to replace the StaticResource lines with DynamicResource

Comment: Thanks Andy +1, why Application.Resources?

Comment: It actually doesn't need to go in to the app resources, it can go in to any resource dictionary that's in scope of the polygons that you're drawing, so if you wanted just a single window of polygons to be styled you can add it to the Window.Resources collection